# Link a new Live Agent Chat to an Existing Case

Tags: liveagent

I have a page where I know the Id of the case I want create a new chat session about. The desired goal is to have the case open for the agent and link the transcript to the existing case. I'm trying to use [findOrCreate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_creating_records_API_map.htm) with Id, but it isn't working. I'm hoping I just got my syntax wrong.

```
liveagent.findOrCreate('Case').map('Id','5000U000000V1FGQA0',true,false,false).saveToTranscript('CaseId').showOnCreate();
liveagent.init("https://d.la2-c2cs-iad.salesforceliveagent.com/chat", "572A00000000000", "00D0U0000000000");
```

Comment: This question seems quite closely related to your previous one. Might be best to just edit this information in there? I am interested to see if any answers pop up though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to edit the previous one as they are kind of different. I think I've got the answer to that one.

Comment: Ah, yeah now it makes sense they're separate questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I misread the Deployment API documentation. I thought you could just shove in values directly in `findOrCreate`, but instead you have to first `addCustomDetail` and then use the name you used there in the `findOrCreate`. In the code below, `{!CaseId}` is referencing a variable in my controller.

```
liveagent.addCustomDetail("CaseId", '{!CaseId}');
liveagent.findOrCreate('Case').map('Id','CaseId',true,true,false).saveToTranscript('CaseId').showOnCreate();
liveagent.init("{!LADomain}", "{!LADeployId}", "{!OrgId}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use to do a findorcreate doFind with an ID:

```
var contactEmail = document.getElementById('email').value;
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.PreChatController.getcontact}', contactEmail, function(result, event){
    if (event.status) {
        document.getElementById('contactId').setAttribute('value', result.Id);
    }
```

and then

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:Contact ID" id="contactId" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact" value="Id,Contact ID" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Id,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Id,true" />
```

Does that help?

Comment: I don't think I want to use the prechat API - I'm trying to avoid having a prechat page all together. The deployment API has similar methods, but the syntax is different.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit old question.

We achieved it inside VF page without using Pre-chat page at all . It can be done in 2 ways.

1. Leverage deployment APi  and addCustomDetail("CaseId", '{!CaseId}')

   ```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
        liveagent.addCustomDetail("CaseId", '{!caseId}');
    liveagent.findOrCreate('Case').map('Id','CaseId',true,true,false).saveToTranscript('CaseId').showOnCreate();
    liveagent.setChatWindowWidth(500);
    liveagent.setChatWindowHeight(500);

    <!-- Chat Deployment Code to initialize, replace with your org's values -->
    liveagent.init('https://d.***.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572530000***', '00D530000***');
    </script>
   ```
2. Update embedded service prechat form details to map existing data inside initESW function

   ```
     embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
                "label":"CaseRecordId",
                "fieldName":"Id",
                "value":"{!caseId}",
                "displayToAgent":true
            }];
            embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatInfo = [{
                "entityName":"Case",
                "showOnCreate":true,
                "linkToEntityName":"LiveChatTranscript",
                "linkToEntityField":"CaseId",
                "saveToTranscript":"CaseId",
                "entityFieldMaps": [{
                    "isExactMatch":true,
                    "fieldName":"Id",
                    "doCreate":false,
                    "doFind":true,
                    "label":"CaseRecordId"
                }]
            }];
   ```